# iOS Firebase Nuget Packages failed to build

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

Good day, I'm using visual studio 2017 , xamarin iOS. I'm trying to implement ios push notifications with firebase, so I've installed Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging and it's dependecies.

But the project is not building and I'm getting errors on each package :
"Download failed. Please download https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/15a4dd6c971f8bbf/FirebaseAnalytics-4.0.4.tar.gz to a file called C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\FAnlytcs-4.0.4.tgz."

I've tried to add both rar and tgz files into the folder, no difference. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Refer to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Comment: it didnt help...